# Sharepoint 2010 Attachment link in External list

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

How to add an Attachment of an item in an External list

Comment: How a custom list has Attach File link, is it possible to have same type of link in External list

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK it's not possible to attach document to external lists.

What you could do is create a regular list, with a content lookup column on your external list (to display columns from your external list) and attach document to this list.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried this but the Custom list is allowing only lookup of values from External list but not entry of new values.